# How to use .NET Custom workflow inside UI Path

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation-4, rpa, uipath

Hay All,
Please any one help me to use custom workflow in UiPath (Custom activity is working ok).
Developed a custom workflow using Visual studio, and create nuguet package, import it in to UiPath package manager. But it doesn’t load the activities panel

### (Please check the images)

[image]
[image]

Comment: try `Activities` in search bar

Comment: Please can you show you code?   Does your class name ends with "Activity"  and inherits from CodeActivity